# ApiException: 10: Developer console is not set up correctly

Tags: android, firebase, oauth, authorization

I am becoming increasingly frustrated by this issue.

Scenario: I Setup Google Authentification using Firebase for my App.
I have added all 3 Sha1 Keys to my Firebase Project Settings (Debug, Release and Published PlayStore App), Added the google-service.json to my Android App.
Added the Sha1 Keys as OAuth 2.0 Client IDs on my console.cloud and created a webapplication I am referencing from my App using the CLient-ID.

On My Phone the Signup using Google works as expected...

As soon as I try and Signup using any other Phone the following Error message shows.

*com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: Developer console is not set up correctly.*

What am I missing, the Console is setup correctly to allow signup using my Phone, why arent other users not able to Signup. Have rechecked the SHA Keys and they are correct.

Comment: Are you sure the user is authenticated with Google on the second device? Maybe the final part of this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help.

Comment: @AlexMamo paywall restricted article